# how to use filter in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

class Status(models.Model):
    someid = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    status_msg = models.CharField(max_length = 2000)

```
so my database look like:
 20     1234567890   'some mdg'
 20     4597434534   'some msg2'
 20     3453945934   'sdfgsdf'
 10     4503485344   'ddfgg'
```

so I have to fetch values contain a giving someid between some values.
so let say

```
  val1 = '1234567890'
    val2  = '4414544544'
```

so my final result should be list containing of 2 entry for id = 20
how to implement this.

i tried using

```
list = Status.objects.filter(someid = 20, value < val2, value > val1)
```

which is wrong?
how to fix this.

thanks.

Comment: sorry for posting this.
I have fix the problem.
list = Status.objects.filter(someid=20, value__lt=val2).filter(value__gt=val1)

Answer (score 10):

Django Query API doesn't use traditional comparison operators. It uses (field)__(operatorname)=(value) style syntax.

Your query would be:

```
list = Status.objects.filter(someid=20, value__lt=val2, value__gt=val1)
```

See Django Docs on [Making Queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [the *__range lookup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
list = Status.objects.filter(someid=20, value__range=(val1+1, val2-1))
```

Be aware, range lookups are 'inclusive', so you have to adapt the range boundaries. If applicable like above, this should result in the very same list as posted by Imran. Range lookups also work with dates.